Is there an open map from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R$?
I'm learning basics of metric spaces and I'm quite stuck with this question.

Is there an open map from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R$?

Lest there be any misinterpretation, let me make it clearer:

$\mathbb R$ has the usual metric.
Look at $[0,1]$ as a subspace of $\mathbb R$.
A map is said to be open if it sends every open set in the domain to an open set in the codomain.
Realize that sets like $[0,1]$, $[0,\frac 12)$ or $(\frac12,1]$ are an open in $[0,1]$ so $f(x)=x$ won't work.
The requested map need not be continuous.

I have tried a lot to find examples but failed. I suspect that there is no such map. What kind of theory should I learn to be able to answer this question?

A strongly Darboux function maps every open interval to $\Bbb{R}$; just take any strongly Darboux function, and restrict its domain to $[0, 1]$. Obviously, such functions are highly discontinuous!

What is the context of this question? If this is supposed to be an exercise or assignment for some elementary real analysis course, I strongly suspect that the map is intended to be continuous (and that you're supposed to swiftly conclude that no such map exists).

@TheoBendit I suspect it's from a test series. I was given this question by a classmate. I told them that continuous image of $[0,1]$ is of the form closed interval $[a,b]$ or singleton ${x}$ so it isn't possible. They insisted that "continuous" is not mentioned.

I'm trying with $f(x) = \tan(\frac{\pi}{2}x -\frac{\pi}{2}(1-x))$ this map $(0,1)\to \Bbb R$ but when I choose where to send ${0,1}$ I always found an image that isn't open of a set like $(\varepsilon,1]$ or $[0,\varepsilon)$

Besides the Conway base-13 function, here's another example which I found on Quora.
Define an equivalence relation $\Delta$ on $[0,1]$ as follows: $$ x\Delta y\iff x-y\in\mathbb Q\cap [0,1]$$
Using axiom of choice, there is a bijection $\varphi$ from the set of equivalence classes $[0,1]/\Delta$ to the set of real numbers $\mathbb R$.
Again, there is a canonical surjection $\tau$ from $[0,1]$ onto $[0,1]/\Delta$ which sends every element to its equivalence class.
$$[0,1]\overset{\tau}{\longrightarrow} [0,1]/\Delta\overset\varphi\longrightarrow \mathbb R$$
Since each equivalence class $[x]$ in $[0,1]/\Delta$ is just a translation of $\mathbb Q\cap [0,1]$, it is dense in $[0,1]$ i.e., given any non-empty open subset $X$ of $[0,1]$, we have $X\cap [x]\neq \emptyset$.   Thus, image of $X$ under $\varphi\circ \tau$ is whole of $\mathbb R$.
